# Kubernetes deployment of a php test application

Tags: php, docker, kubernetes, docker-compose, mariadb

I'm learning Kubernetes at the moment. I learned first docker and made my own Dockerfiles and built my own images. It's a basic PHP application, which tries to connect to a MariaDB database via PDO and which invokes the phpinfo() function. So via docker-compose, it works fine. The next step for me is to run it in a Kubernetes cluster. I tried it in different ways and it doesn't work. I can't reach the index.php on my browser :(

**PHP-Deployment:**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: php-app-deployment
  labels:
    app: php-app
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: php-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: php-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: php-app
        image: amannti/my_php_image:1.2
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

**PHP-Service**:

```
kind: Service 
apiVersion: v1 
metadata: 
  name: php-app-service 
spec: 
  selector: 
    app: php-app 
  ports: 
  - protocol: TCP 
    port: 80 
    targetPort: 80 
    nodePort: 31000 
  type: NodePort
```

**DB-Deployment:**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: db-deployment
  labels:
    app: db
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: db
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: db
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: db
        image: amannti/carpool_maria_db:1.1
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3306
```

**DB-Service:**

```
kind: Service 
apiVersion: v1 
metadata: 
  name: db-service 
spec: 
  selector: 
    app: db 
  ports: 
  - protocol: TCP 
    port: 3306 
    targetPort: 3306
```

I deployed all files on my minikube cluster with *kubectl apply -f fileName*.

The php application only contains this code:

```
<?php
$servername = "oldcarpoolsystem_db_1";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$dbName = "carpoolSystem";

try {
  $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=" . $dbName, 
      $username, $password);
  // set the PDO error mode to exception
  $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  echo "PDO: Connected successfully<br>";
 }
 catch(PDOException $e) {
   echo "PDO: Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br>";
 }

 phpinfo();
```

The database only contains few tables and is named carpoolSystem.

I tried to connect via **http://127.0.0.1:31000/** to my website. But it says "connection refused" :(
On Kubernetes dashboard all services run, but on deployments, pods and replica set the DB part don't run. In pods it says "Waiting: CrashLoopError".

What are my mistakes, what can I learn by this fail?

The whole application runs perfectly with this docker-compose file:

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: amannti/carpool_maria_db:1.1
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    ports:
      - "3306:3306" #Left Container | Right Output
  web:
    image: amannti/my_php_image:1.2
    container_name: php_web
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - "80:80"
```

---

### UPDATE

In the minikube dashboard all deployments, pods and the rest are green... But I have still no access to my application because of connection is refused :/ I tried to access via : (http://127.0.0.1:31000/), but still the same response. Any ideas how to troubleshoot it?

[image: PHP App Service]

---

### UPDATE

**Dockerfile DB:**

```
FROM mariadb/server:latest

COPY dump.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

**Dockerfile PHP:**

```
# This Dockerfile uses the first version of my php image
FROM amannti/my_php_image:1.0

# Copy app's source code to the /src directory
COPY ./src /var/www/html

# The source directory will be the working directory
WORKDIR /
```

Comment: Can you post the dockerfile?

Comment: @Crou I uploaded the dockerfiles, but I don't think it will help much :/

Comment: The logs of this pod say: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.17.0.7. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message

Comment: Question is did you exposed the port 80 for web service inside your docker image. In the same way that mariaDB did in their image, that you are using. Here is [dockerfile](https://hub.docker.com/r/mariadb/server/dockerfile).

Comment: Yeah and it still works with docker-compose

Answer (score 1):

If you do a `kubectl describe pod <YOUR DB POD>` you'll see a bit more informations on why the pod is crashing.

If that's not enough, try `kubectl logs <YOUR DB POD>`, you'll have logs with all errors and warning.

Comment: It says
State: Waiting
Reason: CrashLoopBackOff
Last State: Terminated
Reason: Error
Exit Code: 1

Comment: I think it helped me, I will try to change my deployment because it says: You need to specify one of MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD, MARIADB_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD and MARIADB_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD

Answer (score 1):

You should check on what IP is your minikube configured and use it instead of localhost.

This can be checked in `dashboard` following `Cluster > Nodes > minikube` path, or using this command `minikube ip` and this should be used to check if service is working.

I also strongly advice to check [Set up Ingress on Minikube with the NGINX Ingress Controller](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/ingress-minikube/).